# Update single amplify model field with custom GraphQL mutation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, graphql, aws-amplify, flutter-aws-amplify

I am trying to update single field in Amplify model using GraphQL in Flutter.
As far as I know `Amplify.API.mutate` and `Amplify.DataStore.save` can only update entire models.

In the [doc](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/advanced-workflows/q/platform/flutter/#subset-of-data) in subset-of-data section there is an example how to run custom query to get object.
I tried to analogically write mutation but cannot get it done.

```
 const graphQLDocument = '''mutation update {
  updateUserData(input:
    {
      id: "123",
      name: "John"
    }) {
    email
  }
}''';
```

Then request:

```
final updateUserName = GraphQLRequest<UserData>(
  document: graphQLDocument,
  modelType: UserData.classType,
  decodePath: getTodo, /**/
);

final response = await Amplify.API.mutate(request: updateUserGoal).response;
```

I am not sure what is `decodePath` in this case?
If I don't pass it I get `"message": "No decodePath found",`.

Or maybe I should use `GraphQLOperation` instead of `GraphQLRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

The `decodePath` you can generate from standard mutation:

```
UserData model = UserData(id: '123');
final mutation = ModelMutations.update(model);
```

Then use it:

```
decodePath: mutation.decodePath
```

I still have problem with authorization so I am not sure if that's a correct way to do it. Happy to hear about any suggestions.